# Lot of connections in TIME_WAIT

Tags: windows, networking, time-wait

I had some networking issues on my Windows server, and find out (by using NETSTAT) that I have more than 90,000 (!) connections in TIME_WAIT which didn't closed.

I've changed the TcpTimedWaitDelay param in registry, but apparently a server restart is needed.
Because it's a single production DB server, I can't afford it at the moment.

Is there any way killing a TIME_WAIT connection?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks!
Roei

Comment: Suggestion: ask questions related to networking and servers on superuser.com Stackoverflow is for programmer questions.

Answer (score 1):

> I have more than 90,000 (!) connections in TIME_WAIT which didn't closed.

No you don't. These represent connections which have *already* closed, and whose local port is hanging around for TCP security reasons. They will only be that way for a couple of minutes each. Just wait.